# how the sub select query in the case clause get the parameter value of the main query

Tags: sql

I have two tables both has id columns, but TableA.id is char, and TableB.id is int. now I want to join two tables, but the problem is there are some string in A.id can't be converted to int. Here is the query I wrote

```
SELECT 
    case
        when Column1 is null
        then (select Surname from TableB
              where TableA.id = TableB.id  
             )
        else Column1
        end
FROM TableA
GO
```

the sub select query returns a bunch of records, so my question is that is it possible to run that subquery with the current TableB.id? I am not sure if i explained this clearly, how the subquery get the TableB.id's value of the main query. Thanks

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to ask. An example may help.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir the sub-query that uses values from the outer query. In this case the inner query has to be executed for every row of outer query

Comment: I do know what sub-query is. But still I do not get your question. What do you mean when you say "run that subquery with the current TableB.id" or "TableB.id's value of the main query"? I have to point out that TableB is not defined in outer query. Its scope is subquery. So the things I quoted from you are meaningless for me currently.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir I was trying to join TableA and TableB at first, but since the types are different, there are some value in char can't be converted to int, so here I tried this sub query to get the surname from TableB for each record of TableA

Comment: So basically you want "column1" for each TableA.id, however when "column1" is null then you want "Surname" from TableB if there is a record with the same id. By the way, I assume the types of TableA.Column1 and TableB.Surname are same? If those are correct @JNevill's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, has marked as right answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm following you, but it sounds like the crux of the problem is that you are trying to join on ID, but they are different field types. Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(TableA.Column1, TableB.Surname)
FROM
    TableA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB On
        TableA.ID = Cast(TableB.ID AS Char(64))
```

I was just taking a guess at the CHAR size, but I assume that's ample. Also I'm not sure what DB you are working on so the syntax may need a bit tweaked.

Comment: It works! I didn't realize that convert from int to char is easier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature that can do that. It's called a [Correlated Subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx), although I'm not sure they work inside case statements.